# How to add a datasource in BIRT which is a mysql db accessible only using TCP/IP over SSH?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, ssh, datasource, birt

I want to add datasources in BIRT which are mysql dbs.

For databases which are directly accessible using URL, username & password, I simply provide the parameters to the JDBC driver and datasource is created.

But I have a db which can accessed only from a particular server. I have the SSH private key for logging in to that server. So I SSH to that server and then connect to mysql. (In mysql workbench, I access this db using "TCP/IP over SSH" method.)

I am completely new to BIRT and I want to know whether there's a way to access a mysql db via SSH or should I consider deploying my report on the server which can access the db? If it's possible to connect via SSH, how can I do it?
Please point me to relevant guides/documentation that can be useful to me.

I have seen instructions on the web which have java code snippets to customize stuff in BIRT but I don't know where to put that code. There are just rptdesign files in my project.
(Guides/documents which can help me understand this are also welcome.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am using SSH tunnel for that on OS X.
To establish SSH tunnel to server where MySQL database is running, execute this command:

```
ssh -L localhost:3306:localhost:3306 <username>@<host>
```

Now magic happens. You can connect to your MySQL database using connection URL like this jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306

More info on SSH Tunneling can be found [here](https://freddebostrom.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/ssh-tunnel-from-the-command-line/)